# How to run Xcode UnitTest with Instrument

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, instruments, xctest

I have an app in Xcode, and also Unit Tests. I got the following error in console when I run my Unit Tests (Project -> Test).

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x600000490e50: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I know there is memory management bug in my app, and I am trying to work on that. But the problem came:

I know how to run my app with instrument, which is opening instruments and select simulator then installed app. But I cannot find a way to run my Unit Test in instrument. I tried to add my Unit Test to the scheme, but it didn't seem to work.

Hope some one could help me with this. Please note that I am not asking help for how to solve this malloc error, instead, I just wanna figure out a way to run my Unit Test with the instrument tool. Then I can deal with the error myself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

In "Test Navigator" right click on a test target, test class or test case. From the context menu select "Profile ...":

[image]